# Spark History Server not showing completed Jobs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Context:

- Spark version 3 here (latest as of posting)
- EMR 6.1

1 - Settings are correctly filled - according to the doc : (`/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`)

[image]

2 - History Server Service is Up

[image]

3 - Log Files are produced & present, with open rights

[image]

4 - But still that stubborn History Server UI refuses to display stuff, although the log files for the jobs are produced

[image]

I restarted the hsitory server many time, but no luck
I am seriously out of options here...
Any Ideas what could go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... Instead of restarting the spark history server, I just stopped it.

[image]

And guess, what...
that web uisucker was still there !

[image]

So I headed to the terminal, armed to kill, and found that mastard and gave it a headshot.

[image]

I refreshed... and voilà !

[image]

Sometimes the usage of brute force is the only way out ...
I still wonder what really happened exactly -technically speaking, it is still kinda not really clear to me...

Comment: So hilarious haha. But I know face same issue as you, in the logs it's just stuck at parsing eventlog